# Writing to xml from C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a question about writing to xml with C#. I want this kind of structure;

```
<directory_move>
   <folder_path>
      <source_path>...</source_path>
      ..
      ..
   </folder_path>
   <properties>
      <aaabbcc>....</aaabbcc>
      ..
      ..
   </properties>
</directory_move>
```

I tried so much but could not obtain what I want.
Can you give an advice, how can i do that?

this is my code

```
        XElement element = new XElement("DIRECTORY_MOVE");

        foreach (string sourceDirName in listArray)
        {
            element.Add(new XElement("SOURCE_PATH", sourceDirName));
        }

        element.Add(new XElement("DESTINATION_PATH", destination));


        if (rdbtnDoLater)
        {
            element.Add(new XElement("RDBTNDOLATER", "checked"));
        }

        if (rdbtnDoImmediately)
        {
            element.Add(new XElement("RDBTNDOIMMEDIATELY", "checked"));
        }

        if (chkIsOverwrite)
        {
            element.Add(new XElement("CHKISOVERWRİTE", "checked"));
        }

        if (chkExitWhenFinish)
        {
            element.Add(new XElement("CHKEXITWHENFINISH", "checked"));
        }

        if (chkFolderQuestion)
        {
            element.Add(new XElement("CHKFOLDERQUESTION", "checked"));
        }
```

Comment: Your question needs more details. 
Could you provide the C# code of your attempt to generate the XML ?

Comment: +1 for fixing the OP to include your code.

Comment: See the edit I did in my answer, I think it should be close to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb387019.aspx)

```
XElement example =
    new XElement("directory_move",
        new XElement("folder_path",
            new XElement("source_path", "..."),
            new XElement("source_path", "...")
        ),
        new XElement("properties",
            new XElement("aaabbcc", ...)
        )
    );

example.WriteToFile(...)
```

Edit: The issue with your code is that you're adding everything to the root element, so everything will be children of this root.

What you need to do is reproduce the hierarchy, as I did in my example.

```
XElement root = new XElement("DIRECTORY_MOVE");
XElement folderPath = new XElement("folder_path");

root.Add(folderPath)

foreach (string sourceDirName in listArray)
{
     folderPath.Add(new XElement("SOURCE_PATH", sourceDirName));
}
```

and so on...

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the solution of my problem.